# Is it possible for a ElasticY left axis and a defined rightYaxis domain?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Currently I have a composite line graph in which the lines are over lapping in most areas. For this reason I started to look for a way to modify the [rightY](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.compositeChart.html#rightY__anchor) domain.

```
.rightY(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]))
```

The right axis is a percent and shouldn't go over 1 and appear to works if I don't set elastiY(true). Is there a way to have the left axis Elastic and the right a fixed domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that currently the same elastic setting is used for both left and right axes.

However, `elasticY` is really easy to implement by hand, so you can leave it off and calculate the left domain whenever the chart is rendered or redrawn:

```
    moveChart.on('preRender preRedraw', chart => {
      const ranges = chart._calculateYAxisRanges(true, false);
      chart.y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([ranges.lyAxisMin, ranges.lyAxisMax]));
    })
```

I figured this out by looking at the source for the composite chart, specifically [_prepareLeftYAxis()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/03e9f5d067097235d630dc11042714ed8037b508/src/charts/composite-chart.js#L211-L229) and [_prepareYAxis()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/03e9f5d067097235d630dc11042714ed8037b508/src/charts/composite-chart.js#L115-L132).

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0yr8oj13/51/).

Comment: Again Gordon you've solve another one of my problems. Thanks so much!